# Python script with AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python

I'm kind of new to python. A python script has been running fine - it now dies with the following error:

```
File "/var/newspaper/myscript.py", line 495, in <listcomp>
    return sorted(set([x.lower() for x in self.regex.findall(text)] +
 self.regex_a.findall(text)))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

The lines around the error are as follows:

```
def findall_unique(self, text):
    """
    Find all unique occurrences of keywords in text.
    """
    # Ordinary words are being lower(), abbreviations are returned as is
    return sorted(set([x.lower() for x in self.regex.findall(text)] + self.regex_a.findall(text)))

def get_related_ids(self, words):
    result = set(self.related_ids.get(x.lower()) for x in words)
    result = [x for x in result if x is not None]
    result.sort()
    return result
```

I guess a check is needed to see if x has an attribute lower before attempting to do the set/sorted operations... if it does that return is ok, if not then something else has to be done... can you suggest some code that will fix the error?

Comment: The problem appears to be the result of `self.regex.findall(text)` is returning a list of tuples. This happens when you use capturing parentheses in regular expressions. If you didn't mean to use capturing parens, you either forgot to escape actual parens you meant to match or should use the `(?:)` non-capturing parens form.

Comment: Agreed with @Kurt. The error means that you wrote the function to take a string, but you're not passing it a string.

Comment: Thanks for that - how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
[x.lower() for y in self.regex.findall(text) for x in y]
```

`y` is a tuple, and this lowers all elements of the tuple.

The docs for `re.findall` say:  "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group." This is where the list of tuples comes from. Groups here means that you have parentheses in your regexp that define matching groups.

Comment: So are you saying the return line look like this:

return sorted(set([x.lower() for y in self.regex.findall(text) for x in y] + self.regex_a.findall(text)))

Comment: Yes, except you should cut it into pieces, print them to be sure it is what you want, and then return. But as comments above suggest, the error is more probably that you have unwanted parentheses in your regexp.

Comment: Is there any way I can solve that? I'm a python newbie so need it spelling out please :)

Comment: Yes, you can understand what your regex does using https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, and then fix it.